# Unity deserialize Firebase JSON to object

Tags: c#, json, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to deserialize some json I load from a firebase Database into a custom object, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

I have the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MLResult : IEnumerable<List<int>>
{
    public List<List<int>> results;

    public MLResult(List<List<int>> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    // implementation of the IEnumerable interface
    public IEnumerator<List<int>> GetEnumerator() {
        return results.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I save an `MLResult` object to my Firebase db using:

```
public void SaveData() {    
    List<int> l1 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
    List<int> l2 = new List<int>{6,7,8,9,10};
    List<int> l3 = new List<int>{11,12,13,14,15};
    MLResult r = new MLResult(new List<List<int>>{l1,l2,l3});
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
    var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
}
```

I then try and load it using:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    DBreference.Child("users").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith((DBTask => {
    if (DBTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;

        string data = snapshot.GetRawJsonValue();
        Debug.Log(data);

        MLResult res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MLResult>(data);
        //test by printing out each number
        foreach (var item in res.results)
        {
            foreach (var x in item)
            {
                Debug.Log(x);
            }
        }
    }
}));
}
```

When I print the raw json result in the `data` variable, it is as follows: `[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]`

However the following part, does not do anything, when if I use the same code in the SaveData method before serialising it prints all the individual list items as it should.

```
foreach(var item in res.results) {
    foreach(var x in item) {
        Debug.Log(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you to fix the MLResult class. NEVER try to inherit any collection class or interface like IEnumerable, list , array and so on. It will only bring a lot of different bugs

```
public class MLResult 
{
    public List<List<int>> results {get; init;}

    //or if you want it private
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    List<List<int>> results;

    public MLResult(List<List<int>> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public IEnumerator<List<int>> GetResultsEnumerator()
    {
        return results.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

test enumerator

```
    var enumerator = r.GetResultsEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var em = enumerator.Current.GetEnumerator();
        while (em.MoveNext())
        {
            var val = em.Current;
            Debug.Log(val);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without `IEnumerable` how can iterate over the `MLResult` object to get the inner list?

Comment: @RishtarCode47 See my test code

Comment: thank you that works. Your advice actually helped me to solve it another way aswell. I added `public List<int> GetInnerList(int index){return results[index];}` as a method in the `MLResult` class.